# SilverStripe update notifications for CMS and Framework, and modules installed

Tags: module, updates, silverstripe

I have seen Composer for updating modules, the Framework and the CMS. It seems easy for an experienced programmer. But for a beginner its a headache.

So my question, does it have a module or a coding somewhere to notify new available versions etc? Similar to how WordPress notifies the CMS user of available updates.

Comment: thanks @3dgoo. I really need an english course ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite what you're after because you still need to be using composer and it only emails you updates, but this is something worth looking at:

https://github.com/XploreNet/silverstripe-composerupdates

Comment: That module is a really nice start. It would be cool to extend it out to display the data in the CMS.

Comment: Yes, I approve this it's a very nice approach. I will check changes updates on this module. Thanks!